# Solaris 10 openssl version 1.0.1k but apache httpd not compiling,showing version too old-0.9.8a

Tags: solaris, openssl, apache-httpd

I have compiled openssl from source on my Solaris machine to a newer location apart from the default one. When I set the newly compiled ssl path in PATH variable and LD_Library path and then compile APACHE 64 bit with CFLAGS and CPPFLAGS and CXXFLAGS all set to -O2 -mcpu=v9 -m64 with apr, apr-util and pcre and ssl, the compiler of apache httpd 2.4.10 goes to the correct directory where i have installed ssl 1.0.1k and but shows me that checking ssl version openssl 0.9.8a >= FAILED. openssl version too old.

When i check the openssl version,its giving me 1.0.1k

I even tried the steps as: ./config --prefix=/export/home /Apache24/openssl-1.0.1k thread shared solaris64-gcc -m32.....this command gives that its already configured on sparcv8.

How can i resolve this, I have to compile apache 2.4.10 with 64bit with SSL.

The below is the message i get when i run httpd compilation:

```
checking for OpenSSL...
  checking for user-provided OpenSSL base directory... /export/home/Apache24/ssl
  adding "-I/export/home/Apache24/ssl/include" to CPPFLAGS
  setting MOD_CFLAGS to "-I/export/home/Apache24/ssl/include  "
  setting ab_CFLAGS to "-I/export/home/Apache24/ssl/include  "
  adding "-L/export/home/Apache24/ssl/lib" to LDFLAGS
  setting MOD_LDFLAGS to "-L/export/home/Apache24/ssl/lib  "
checking for OpenSSL version >= 0.9.8a... FAILED
configure: WARNING: OpenSSL version is too old
no
checking whether to enable mod_ssl... configure: error: mod_ssl has been
requested but can not be built due to prerequisite failures
```

Answer (score 1):

Check where is installed this new ssl package and use --with-ssl=DIR when exec configure script

Comment: I have given the correct path as stated above for the new ssl directory where i have compiled in --with-ssl=new openssl directory path.still it states openssl version too old

Comment: Have you run again configure script? Where is installed new ssl? what exactly have you write after -with-ssl?

Comment: i have compiled openssl 1.0.1k in the path /export/home/Apache24/ssl and when i compile httpd i give --with-ssl=/export/home/Apache24/ssl -enable-ssl -enable-so

Comment: You should install openssl. This compilations is not usable. Moreover when install apache you mod_ssl should use openssl libraries

Comment: i have compiled openssl then make and then make install...this installs openssl in the directory specified and mod_ssl is for APache 1.3 , i am using apache 2.4 which has it by default

Comment: Check if you have in this directory all binaries, header files and libraries. And clear old config of configure script

Answer (score 0):

Check your --with-ssl DIR, if you want to use new OpenSSL (in another path) install it in other path and indicate it in your Configure command argument .

**Example for AIX 7.1 :**

**1/Example OpenSSL 1.1.1m Installation :**

```
cd /appli/tmp
cat openssl-1.1.1m.tar.gz | gzip -d  | tar -xvf -
cd /appli/tmp/openssl-1.1.1m
export HOME_SSL=/appli
mkdir -p $HOME_SSL/openssl
export PATH=/usr/bin:/etc:/usr/sbin:/usr/ucb:/usr/bin/X11:/sbin:
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
export CC=/usr/bin/gcc
./Configure aix-cc  --prefix=$HOME_SSL/openssl --openssldir=$HOME_SSL/openssl LDFLAGS=-R/opt/freeware/64/lib shared zlib-dynamic shared
make
make install
```

**2/Example Apache 2.4.52 Installation (with arp) using openssl 1.1.1m of 1/ :**

```
cd /appli/tmp
cat httpd-2.4.52.tar.gz| gzip -d | tar -xvf  -  
cp apr-1.7.0.tar.gz httpd-2.4.52/srclib
cp apr-util-1.6.1.tar.gz httpd-2.4.52/srclib
cd httpd-2.4.52/srclib
cat apr-util-1.6.1.tar.gz | gzip -d | tar -xvf  -
cat xvf apr-1.7.0.tar.gz | gzip -d  | tar -xvf 
mv apr-1.7.0 apr
mv apr-util-1.6.1 apr-util
rm apr-util-1.6.1.tar.gz apr-1.7.0.tar.gz 

export LIBS=-ldl
export LDFLAGS="-ldl"
export PATH=/usr/bin:/etc:/usr/sbin:/usr/ucb:/usr/bin/X11:/sbin:/appli/openssl/bin
mkdir -p /appli/apache
cd /appli/tmp/httpd-2.4.52
./configure -C --prefix=/appli/apache--enable-so --enable-ssl=static  --with-ssl=/appli/openssl/  --enable-rewrite --enable-module-rewrite --with-included-apr --with-pcre=/usr/local/pcre
make clean 
make
make install
```